# Why was this question closed as needing details or clarity?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

[Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440511/195804) is closed as "needs details or clarity", but I can't figure out why. To me the question perfectly clear: they post a minimal example of their code, post the error message that they get and ask how they can fix it. The only thing that I can see that might be wrong with this question is that they posted an off-site link to their log file, but it's not necessary to open that link to understand the question.

I found this question by googling because I got the same error, and the only answer there didn't help me. And looking at the votes, I'm not alone. At the time of writing this, the question has 15 upvotes and the answer only has 1 upvote.

I apparently ran into this problem before and posted [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1550051) with my solution. I would like to post that comment as an answer, but I can't since the question is closed. Since answers are more visible than comments, posting this comment as an answer could potentially help people with the same problem in the future. Posting this as an answer would also allow me to elaborate on how I changed the permission settings in case someone doesn't know how to do that.

Why was this closed? How can it be edited so that it can be reopened? Based on the score of the question, this seems to be a relatively common problem, so reopening it and allowing more answers could potentially help future users with the same problem.

Comment: I voted to reopen, I think you're right.

Comment: well I have no idea why it was closed, but imho it would be better if you ask a new question with your data and log file and then add a self-answer as it is after 5 years completly unclear (and untestable) if the old problem could have been solved with your solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's the same error, so if I were to re-ask it myself it wouldn't be very different from the existing question. As the existing answer to the question suggests, different solutions might work for different people, so I think it's better to keep all the answers in one place.

Comment: Maybe it was closed at the time because it was not reproducible (without knowing more about the setup of the user and/or the contents of the external log file).

Comment: it was closed as not reproducible, it's since been re-opened but I don't think your answer answers  the question asked, rather confirming the closure was correct